# When running MassTransit for first time in debugging, Error creating queue, insufficient privileges

Tags: c#, msmq, masstransit

I've got an MVC site and a processing service both set up to use MassTransit. I had to delete the queues, as I was getting an issue where the mt_ queues weren't being created for me when I started on another machine. Now, when I run my application, I get an error about not being able to create the queues.

My configuration;

```
        sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration( );
        sbc.SetCreateMissingQueues( true );
        sbc.ReceiveFrom(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusQueue"] );
        sbc.UseMsmq( );
        sbc.UseControlBus( );
        sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient( );
        sbc.Subscribe(
            subs => subs.LoadFrom( Kernel ) );
```

The ServiceBusQueue is set to msmq://localhost/sample_queue

I had this problem once before, but then when I put the code into the final application, the problem went away. I'm running Visual Studio as administrator.

What permissions do I need? Where do I set them?

Comment: I saw this sort of problem posted recently but can't find it now. The problem was lack of permissions for creating a file for a component rather then lack of permissions for creating the queue. Hope that helps.

Comment: There is a bug in the release you are using that fails to write out the proxy DLL due to permissions. The updated package will be released by the end of the week. In the meantime, you can use the assemblies from the /develop build on teamcity.codebetter.com - in particular the Magnum.dll assembly is needed and has the fix.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I posted this on the Google group,not realizing I had put this particular issue here a few days earlier (it was a separate issue at that point). This did fix the issues I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by the bug fix mentioned by Chris.